# Write JSON to Solr via HTTP/Post

Tags: c#, json, rest, solr

I am writing to Solr using JSON via HTTP/POST from a C#/Winforms/.NET4.0 app to speed up indexing and using the code below. I write a document to solr (based on these [instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON/)) but keep getting a '400 bad request'. The JSON appears to be clean and no issues.

It seems to be a syntax issue but I have been wrestling with this for last many hours to no avail. Any ideas on what is awry? All help appreciated.

Here is the URI string being posted

```
"http://localhost:8080/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' [ {\"UUID\":\"d2a174e4-81d6-487f-b68d-392be5d3d47a\",\"Extension\":\".AVI\",\"VideoFileName\":\"Clip 1.avi\"} ' ]"

string uri = http://localhost:8080/solr/update/json;

public bool WriteJSONToSolr(string uri, string json)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri + " -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' [ " + json + " ' ]" );
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
            Stream stream = null;
            try
            { // send the Post
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   //Count bytes to send
                stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         //Send it
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            if (response == null) return false;

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Stop using true/false as control flow.

Comment: You are't disposing your stream, just closing it.

Comment: Don't catch ANY and ALL exceptions, like you do when you return false the first time. You are also not disposing your WebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting then you will need to use add and doc in your json element. You'll also want to add a commit so that the index is updated. You can also remove the parameters from your uri as you can add them in the web request object. Lastly, you should have your collection name in the uri.

```
string json = "{\"add\":{\"doc\":{"
  + "\"UUID\":\"d2a174e4-81d6-487f-b68d-392be5d3d47a\","
  + "\"Extension\":\".AVI\","
  + "\"VideoFileName\":\"Clip 1.avi\"}},";
  + "\"commit\":{}}";
string uri = "http://localhost:8080/solr/collection/update";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
Stream stream = null;

try {
  request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
  stream = request.GetRequestStream();
  stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
catch {
  return;
}
finally {
  if (stream != null) {
    stream.Close();
  }
}
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
if (response == null) {
  return;
}
```

If you are inserting multiple objects to solr you can add multiple add objects or doc objects to the json. For example...

```
json = "{add:{doc:{keys:values}}, add:{doc:{keys:values}}, commit:{}}"
```

or

```
json = "{add:{doc:{keys:values}, doc:{keys:values}}, commit:{}}"
```

While your debugging this watch the log for solr. It will alert you to any problems with that may be happening on the solr side.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you are passing a correct json data with -d option.. Look at the following formatting code in your code.

```
" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' [ " + json + " ' ]"
```

Assume, your json data is `{"name":"sam"}` Then, the above formatting results to

```
-H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' [{"name":"sam"} ' ]
```

You are passing a json data with missing ].

Apart from that, your approach for updating a document in solr index is wrong. Take a look at the following simple code. 
[BTW: You may pass the 'commit' argument in the url].

```
public async Task PostAsync()
{
    string json = "{\"add\": {\"doc\": {"
        + "\"id\":\"12345\","
        + "\"firstname\":\"Sam\","
        + "\"lastname\":\"Wills\","
        + "\"dob\":\"2016-12-14T00:00:00Z\""
        + "}}}";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:8983/solr/people/update/json?wt=json&commit=true";
        var jsonContent = new StringContent(json);
        await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), jsonContent);
    }
}
```

If you want to update a specific field instead of whole document [partial update], use the following code snippet.

```
public async Task PartialPostAsync()
{
    string json = "{\"add\": {\"doc\": {"
        + "\"id\":\"12345\","
        + "\"lastname\":{\"set\":\"George\"}"
        + "}}}";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:8983/solr/people/update/json?wt=json&commit=true";
        var jsonContent = new StringContent(json);
        await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), jsonContent);
    }
}
```

'id' field is an unique field.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget putting a `space` char before `-H`?

Comment: Unfortunately been all those iterations adding space before after etc. No luck :-(. Incidentally no error message back from Solr either just a 400 bad request, InnerException is null. Thx

Comment: but why do you still post the json str when you have already put the json in the url?

Comment: hmm..not sure that makes a different. I was trying diff. combinations.

Comment: so why not try just to do `GetResponse()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today.

Try these two things

1) Keep in mind that you can NOT send a json string like

```
[{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"","D":"Washington"}]
```

instead you may have to massage the json to be more like

```
[{"A":"1","B":"0","D":"Washington"}]
```

Solr does not like empty values.

2) This second trick that helps (when sending data to solr via '**curl**') : Try replacing all Double Quotes in your json string with two Double Quotes before you send the request to solr.

`json = json.Replace(@"""", @"""""");`

Answer (score 0):

The reasong that your code isn't working, is because you are using cURL syntax in .Net.

cURL is an executable that sends and receives HTTP requests and .Net is a framework for programming applications.

They are not the same.

To make it work with .Net you first should post to the correct uri, and you need to set the correct ContentType property like such:

```
var uri = "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/json";
using (var r = WebRequest.Create(uri))
{
    r.ContentType = "application/json";
    r.Method = "POST";
    using (var rs = r.GetRequestStream())
        rs.Write // your data
    // get response
    // return response data
}
```

That said, why inflict pain upon yourself? Just use a SolR connector that already has a typed API for SolR operations!

https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ for example!

But if you don't want to use that, then at least use a modern HTTP API like https://nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code after convert json to stream bytes

```cs
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    byte[] bodyBytes;
    try
    {
        string body = BodyFormatter.CreateBody(loggingEvent, _parameters);
        bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorHandler.Error("Failed to create body", e);
        return;
    }

    HttpWebRequest request = BuildRequest();
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(r =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(r))
            {
                stream.BeginWrite(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length, c =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        stream.EndWrite(c);
                        request.BeginGetResponse(a =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var response = request.EndGetResponse(a);
                                if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                    ErrorHandler.Error("Got failed response: " + ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                                response.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                ErrorHandler.Error("Failed to get response", e);
                            }
                        }, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ErrorHandler.Error("Failed to write", e);
                    }
                }, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Error("Failed to connect", e);
        }
    }, null);
}
```